# Javascript not executing properly on wordpress site for guest related to encoding

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I used elementor html box tool to inject a small calculator into a blog. The calculator has chinese character as javascript objects used for mapping. The calculator works fine when I'm logging but it does not when I'm in not logging in. I used console command and saw the chinese characters are not getting interpreted properly. It's showing ASCII like

&#19985
&#20133

I made sure the encoding is set to utf-8.I tried different solution from Google and nothing seems to work.

Comment: `I tried different solution from Google` - which solutions? Surely there's a `;` missing in those HTML entitities - shouldn't it be &#19985; and &#20133;

Comment: I couldn't add the ; or auto converts the actual character. I look at database to ensure it's utf-8 not utf-7, I looked at config file to ensure it had the correct utf-8 encoding, I tried commenting some of the lines out and still don't work

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve the issue by moving the entire script externally instead of running inline. It seems the script won't fully load when I'm not log in as admin. Not sure why that would be the cause, but it did resolve this way. For anyone else running wordpress with elementor and is having this issue, can try my method.